# Transform Physical Point To Index using ITK

Tags: c++, dicom, itk

I am trying to get HU value along a trajectory. The target coordinates and the tangent to this target (hence the trajectory) are calculated using Matlab on a mesh file, giving a set of xyz coordinates and the direction vector (tangents). Then, I load the dicom file (from which the mesh was extracted but not the binary mask itself which was used to get the Mesh) in C++ using ITK. Then, I used the function `image->TransformPhysicalPointToIndex(point, pixelIndex);`. I read the target x,y,z coordinates of the target and construct a vector of double[3] with coordinates at every 0.02 mm from the target till 2mm from the target. When I call the function `image->TransformPhysicalPointToIndex(point, pixelIndex);`, it always returns false, as in the points don't lie in the image. 
So, after the default values, I changed the origin of image as the value in the Metadata with tag **(0020|0032) Image Position (Patient) = -3.125-12\13.125**.

With this, all the Physical points lie in the image but the HU values are wrong (the pixel indexes are on the top-left, instead of bottom right). 
Can anyone let me know the steps I need to follow to achieve this task?

Comment: @blowekamp may be you can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse [ImageDirections](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageBase.html#a23ebc76de3b60bb1eeabf66cd4dabc48), by multiplying each row vector by -1. But you will also need to move the origin to the bottom-right to keep physical image extent the same.

Comment: How would I get the origin to the bottom-right? Is there a need to shift the origin/spacing for my purpose or is there a work around?

Comment: You could calculate the extent of the image (spacing*size), and modify the origin like this: origin+=extent*directionVector. Use GetOrigin() and SetOrigin(). This needs to be done for each coordinate, obviously.

But your problem appears to be that Matlab code is not properly respecting DICOM patient space (physical space), you are better of fixing that.

Comment: I actually did exactly that, the spacingsize if the tag _pixel spacing_ right? What I can't seem to figure out is which tag is a better measure of the depth?

Comment: Depth is the difference between Image Position Patient of slices n and n+1.

Comment: That's how DICOM standard says it should be calculated. Things get complicated if that difference in position (when viewed as a movement vector) is not orthogonal to the slice - when there is shear (not all edge angles are right angles).